# Get RSSI From Devices Quickly On Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

So I’m pondering an application that would require gathering bluetooth RSSI information for any number of surrounding android devices quickly (< 1 second per device, preferably faster) and continuously. It *could* pair with the devices as long as that pairing doesn’t require any user interaction or previous interaction between the phones.

I don’t have any prior experience with bluetooth, just the reading I’ve done over the last couple of days; I’m looking for a little direction.

What are the options for this, if any? It looks like someone is doing something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911102/core-bluetooth-constant-rssi-updates-of-in-range-devices) with iOS and BLE. I could accept BLE as a limitation if that drastically simplifies things.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the RSSI like that on Android during an inquiry:

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, (short) 0);
```

But be carefull, some devices do not support reading the RSSI.