# How to scan BLE devices in Background?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, scanning

I want to scan BLE devices on the background as like a foreground. But my iOS app doesn't work as I expect. Below is my AppDelegate class code.

```
private var centralManager : CBCentralManager!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)return true
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    print("entering foreground...")
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("entered background...")

    print(centralManager.state)
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
}


func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .poweredOn {
        print("Bluetooth is On")
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    } else {
        print(central.state)
    }
}
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    print("\nName   : \(peripheral.name ?? "(No name)")")
    print("RSSI   : \(RSSI)")

    let name = peripheral.name ?? ""
    if name.contains("ETGuardian") {

        let DetailData = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"]
        let DiscoveredData = String(describing: DetailData)

        print(DiscoveredData)

        for ad in advertisementData {
            print("AD Data: \(ad)")
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Please help me to scan app in background state as like a foreground.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background Scanning for BLE in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631772/background-scanning-for-ble-in-swift)

Comment: I tried this solution, but not solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Docs: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518986-scanforperipherals)

> Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are
>   allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must
>   explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the
>   serviceUUIDs parameter. The CBCentralManager scan option is ignored
>   while scanning in the background.

For background scanning to work you need to specify serviceUUIDs.